# div in a cell with text wrapping

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div in a cell of a table and I am using it to link to somewhere else.  The trouble is that it is not showing up in line like a regular link blah blah would.  Any ideas on how to get the text and div to all appear in line?

`<td>Watch videos over the <div class="bodyLinks" id="chemvidslink">metric system and dimensional analysis</div>.</td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a span instead of a div.  It would be much easier.

```
<td>Watch videos over the <span class="bodyLinks" id="chemvidslink">metric system and dimensional analysis</span>.</td>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bxjX6/)

Comment: Perfection!!  I am still new to css and still learning so many things.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem, please make sure to mark this as the answer to help anybody searching for a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Since divs are block level elements by default, change it via CSS to an inline element:

```
td div {
    display:inline;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ghj2W/)**

Answer (score 0):

Make the div an inline element.

```
display: inline
```

An inline element is displayed inline. For instance, if this was a link, it would be inline. If there was an image below this, it would not. Inline elements are inline with the text surrounding them.